# link an interface with the database in android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-sqlite, android-spinner, android-tablelayout

I want to create an android application with columns and rows, from where user will choose items and create an order. I've already made my own database in SQLiteBrowser with 5 columns.
I added this db in "assets" of android project. Also i created an interface. The question is, how to link all this infromation with my interface? For instance, how i can add information about addresses in Spinner and information about items into tablelayout from the db?
I am new at android development, sorry, if i couldn't explain it properly.
Any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: First of all you should try to retrieve these values from sqlite database .  You may like to read a little more about sqlite data base - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am using DBAdapter. All you need is just specify youd DB name and path. If you want to populate some View you need create adpter class. Enjoy: http://www.2shared.com/document/Ik6fFuth/DBAdapter.html